# Array Bitmap em um único arquivo

Tags: c#, bitmap

Estou fazendo uma aplicação para o Solidwoks e baixei alguns exemplos, nele são usados algumas imagens BMP como a vista a seguir:

[image: Bitmap com várias imagens]

Estas imagens são utilizadas como imagens em menus da seguinte forma no código C#:

```
BitmapHandler iBmp = new BitmapHandler();
cmdGroup = iCmdMgr.CreateCommandGroup2(mainCmdGroupID, TitleDr, ToolTipDr, "", -1, ignorePrevious, ref cmdGroupErr);
cmdGroup.LargeIconList = iBmp.CreateFileFromResourceBitmap("EngToolsSW.ToolbarLarge.bmp", thisAssembly);
cmdGroup.SmallIconList = iBmp.CreateFileFromResourceBitmap("EngToolsSW.ToolbarSmall.bmp", thisAssembly);
cmdGroup.LargeMainIcon = iBmp.CreateFileFromResourceBitmap("EngToolsSW.MainIconLarge.bmp", thisAssembly);
cmdGroup.SmallMainIcon = iBmp.CreateFileFromResourceBitmap("EngToolsSW.MainIconSmall.bmp", thisAssembly);
```

Ou seja, ele busca as imagens separadamente dentro de um mesmo bitmap como se fosse ou Array de imagens. Na documentação do Solidworks fala dessa forma:

> The bitmap or PNG file should contain all of the images for all of the large buttons and separators for this CommandGroup, in a single bitmap for both parent and child toolbars. Each image of each button must be 24x24. The images should use a 256-color palette. Use gray (RGB 192, 192, 192) for transparent areas in your graphic.
>
> You can only set this property for the top-level CommandGroup.

disponível neste [link](http://help.solidworks.com/2014/english/api/sldworksapi/SolidWorks.Interop.sldworks%7ESolidWorks.Interop.sldworks.ICommandGroup%7ELargeIconList.html).

Como é possível criar um bitmap desses?

Answer (score 1):

Basicamente você adiciona o arquivo ao seu projeto no Visual Studio. Depois você abre a caixa de diálogo com as propriedades do arquivo. Lá vai ter um campo com o nome "Build Action" define ele como "Embedded Resource". Depois disso você vai poder acessar esses arquivos da mesma forma que você está fazendo no exemplo. É só utilizar a dll que o Visual Studio gera.

Referência: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319292

Comment: Ok Lucas, já cheguei a usar a opção de "Embedded Resource" para imagens no projeto, porém minha dúvida é porque é usado um único arquivo bitmap com várias imagens que podem ser usadas separadamente de acordo com um index da classe `SmallIconList`, não entendo como é possível criar um bitmap desses com várias imagens.

Comment: @DanielMasarin , se chamar somente isso `cmdGroup.LargeIconList`. É retornado um array de bitmaps?

Comment: Não, é retornado uma string com o local do bitmap.